# joomla add custom tab and custom fields to article

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

first i show image: http://www.upload.ee/image/4675395/Untitled.png , to understand my idea better

I am using joomla 2.5.14 and I want to add another menu option for Extra Fields (It would have 10 fields - ID, Picture URL, Video URL, etc).
The new menu would be saved as vod_items table. The menu would be added where are the Publishing Options, Configure Edit Screen, etc.
That option should be available in every article.

Is there a simple way to add that option to Joomla or is there any kind of a code or plugin to do that?

Kind regards,
Aimar.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom plugin to add more custom fields on Article manager or any other core component of Joomla.

You can follow following link for creating a plugin for adding custom fields to Article manager.

Reference : [Adding custom fields to core components using a plugin](https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_core_components_using_a_plugin)

**Note :** Don't edit the core component as all changes will be lost in future update of Joomla.